# Authentication in SSRS and Lightswitch application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have written application in which I have used SSRS and Lightswitch. Lighswitch application is used for data entry portion for the user. And SSRS is used for generating reports and graphs from the data entered through Lightswitch App.

I have configured basic authentication on SSRS side and Windows authentication on Lightswitch app. When a user hits the application SSRS reports comes by default. Since I have setup authentication on SSRS side it asks for the user credentials for the first time. Also when user switch to lightswitch app for data entry it again asks for user creds again. So basically user has to enter creds two times which is not good thing as per usability.

So I was wondering if there is any way user only has to login once at the start of the application? Please let me know if it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use Windows Authentication for SSRS and configure to meet the requirements so no user logins are required by either app. This is more secure, as well as more usable.